# RCT Linking Manager file not found

Tags: xcode, xcode6, react-native

I want to use react native library `RCTLinkingManager` which shows up in menu under "Libraries > RCTLinkingManager.xcodeproj".

However when i add it to `iOS/AppDelegate.m` like so:

```
#import "RCTLinkingManager.h"

// @implementation ...
```

Build fails with 'RCTLinkingManager.h' file not found. I tried to clean the product and clean build with no luck.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You have to add `$(SRCROOT)/../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS` to your "Header Search Paths" in the Build Config of your project. You can find more info [on the official React documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking-libraries-ios.html#step-3)

Comment: `$(SRCROOT)/../node_modules/react-native/Libraries` works for me

Comment: In addition to adding ```$(SRCROOT)/../node_modules/react-native/Libraries``` I had to mark it as recursive searching as opposed to non-recursive.

Comment: That did it for me, CallMeNorm. Files may have moved around since the original answer.

Comment: You are right @Sébastien Saunier. But to be more accurate, it should only add the search path for RCTLinkingManager.h file. And that is: $(SRCROOT)/../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS

Comment: Unfortunately still doesn't work for me. I've gone through the docs 3-4 times no with no luck. It still says it can't find it. I'm on RN 0.38 and using Xcode 9.

Answer (score 41):

Kindly make sure that you place the

```
#import <React/RCTLinkingManager.h>
```

in the Appdelegate.m file above the

```
#ifdef FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED
```

it worked for us.

Comment: This is exactly what our problem was. Sometimes the solution is easier than we expect it to be! :)  Thank you @mussabaheen.

Comment: it worked, but why?

Comment: Kudos... worked for me as well...

Answer (score 18):

I had a similar issue only when I've done the archive/release version... that happen because the import was made under the `#if DEBUG`. So make sure you put the import in the proper place otherwise you can get *Use of undeclared identifier 'RCTLinkingManager'* error

Comment: thanks! spent so much time on this and missed this little thing!

Comment: ah! that _sneaky_ `#ifdef FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED` !!

Comment: I didn't notice it at all <3

Answer (score 10):

Anyone who is facing this issue for a react-native archive for ios platform just place

```
#import <React/RCTLinkingManager.h>"
```

after the first line

```
"#import "AppDelegate.h"" in the AppDelegate.m file.
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using React Native and the command line, Sébastien's modification proposal is to be made to `ios/<yourproject>.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` by adding

```
"$(SRCROOT)/../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS",
```

to the `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` lists (4 locations)

Answer (score 2):

Oh man. similar to this answer:

> Anyone who is facing this issue for a react-native archive for ios
> platform just place
>
> #import <React/RCTLinkingManager.h>"  after the first line
>
> "#import "AppDelegate.h"" in the AppDelegate.m file.

I had to put it above this line (for react-native@0.70)

```
#if RCT_NEW_ARCH_ENABLED
```