# Why cant xcode find <React/RCTLinkingManager.h>?

Tags: react-native, share, react-native-ios, deep-linking

I'm working on a ejected react native news app and want to add the ability to open the app from an external link. The problem is that xcode cant find the file that is needed to configure this.

This link includes steps to take when manually link: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios#manual-linking

After those steps i continued with the steps for iOS: 
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking

After following theese steps, Xcode still cant find the items. I have added $(SRCROOT)/../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS to my Header Search Paths. Solution from this [RCT Linking Manager file not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31860715/rct-linking-manager-file-not-found), but still nothing. Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RCT Linking Manager file not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31860715/rct-linking-manager-file-not-found)

Comment: I've already looked at that, but the sulution provided didnt work for me

Comment: what's u react native versiyon also npm/node

Comment: sdkVersion: 34.0.0,  npm: 6.10.2

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the header search paths you have in the xcode?

Comment: Thanks to everyone who commented on this thread. Since I'm using Expo, i dont need to link and only need to refeer to the Expo documentaion. Where linking is not required. Im closing this

Answer (score 1):

Anyone who is facing this issue for a react-native archive for ios platform just place

```
#import <React/RCTLinkingManager.h>"
```

after the first line

```
"#import "AppDelegate.h"" in the AppDelegate.m file.
```

This thing worked for me.

Comment: not worked for me