# <React/RCTLinkingManager.h> file not found

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, react-native, deep-linking

Am developing react native project with Expo 32 SDK. Now am integrating deep link in my project. In Android its works fine but in IOS. while I try to run my project in xcode it returns this error. I tried to add ROOT path in Header Search path and tried manually link, Deleted my DerivedData etc but no use I don't know how to fix it.
 `Xcode version 11.3.1, "native-base":"2.4.2" , "React":"16.13.1"`
I tried to updated latest version of React.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the following import in the file 'AppDelegate.m'

```
#import <React/RCTLinkingManager.h>
```

above the line

```
#ifdef FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED
```

as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64712212/5615371) as a solution?

Comment: sorry but I don't have #ifdef FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED line in my AppDelegate.m

Comment: well then just add it after your other imports in AppDelegate.m. Have you tried that?